# Calculate the mean value of a dataframe column twice based on a valid other column

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to calculate the mean value of a column twice: one time for all values where `name` contains a valid string and second time for values if `name` contains an empty string or np.nan.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[np.nan,1],['kkk',4],['ggg',2], ['',3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','value'])
```

Here:

- mean 1 (valid cols mean): (4+2)/2 = 3
- mean 2 (in-valid cols mean): (1+3)/2 = 2

I could do this via iterating over each row but this is not a very pythonic way. I guess that must be a much more pythonic and smooth solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
print(df.loc[~df.name.isin([np.nan, '']), 'value'].mean())
print(df.loc[df.name.isin([np.nan, '']), 'value'].mean())
```

Output:

```
3.0
2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first unify your non-valid rows by replacing empty strings with `np.nan`, then extract all the rows with a `np.nan` in the `name` column and take the mean of the value column. Afterwards, you could do the inverse of the above to get the mean of the valid rows.

```
data = [[np.nan,1],['kkk',4],['ggg',2], ['',3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','value'])

replaced_empties = df.replace("", np.nan)
mean_2 = replaced_empties[replaced_empties.name.isnull()].value.mean()
mean_1 = replaced_empties[~replaced_empties.name.isnull()].value.mean()

print(mean_1) # 3.0
print(mean_2) # 2.0
```